# undefined when trying access data from JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

How can I access a specific data from following JSON without getting undefined?

```
var myObj = '{"isTrue":"true","id":"1"}';
var theKey = 'isTrue';
alert(myObj[theKey]); //I get undefined here
```

Comment: It looks like you are using a json string instead of object

Comment: You haven't parsed the string , put myObj = JSON.parse(myObj) in the 2nd line

Comment: you should use JSON.parse(myObj) to convert json to javascript object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse that JSON as String before to access any property from it.

```
JSON.parse(myObj)
```

```js
var myObj = '{"isTrue":"true","id":"1"}';
var theKey = 'isTrue';

alert(JSON.parse(myObj)[theKey]);
```